# How to display a.m instead of AM using date-and-time library?

Tags: javascript

Given a string like

```
const time = "06:15:00"
```

This is 6:15 am

```
date.format(time, "h:mm A") // 6:15 AM
```

I want 6:15 a.m.

```
date.format(time, "h:mm aa")
```

doesn't work for some reason

Is there a way?

Comment: You can simply use string replace method.

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-and-time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add [`meridiem`](https://github.com/knowledgecode/date-and-time/blob/master/PLUGINS.md#meridiem) plugin

```js
date.plugin('meridiem')

const time = date.parse('06:15:00', 'hh:mm:ss') 

console.log(date.format(time, 'hh:mm aa'))
```

```html
<script src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/knowledgecode/date-and-time/a5f31dcb3fe1bd02fd8ff7770552c73a4401d0a1/date-and-time.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/knowledgecode/date-and-time/a5f31dcb3fe1bd02fd8ff7770552c73a4401d0a1/plugin/meridiem.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```